# Final variable being changed without any = statements

Tags: java, arrays, swing, integer

I'm making an autoclicking project in java for personal use, and using the following method to get coordinates of a click from a class that extends MouseAdapter. The click is being done on a JFrame.

```
            int[] mouseCoordinates = new int[2];   //The coordinates of the click
            mouseCoordinates = mouseListenerExample.getCoordinates();

            final int[] baseCoordinates = mouseCoordinates; //The base coordinates (no click) which is this problem//

            int[][] totalCoordinates = new int[4][2];  //An array that collects all coordinates of 4 mouse clicks


            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){ //the goal is to get the coordinates of 4 clicks

                while (mouseCoordinates[0] == baseCoordinates[0]){
                    mouseCoordinates = mouseListenerExample.getCoordinates(); //The problem occurs here: when mouseListenerExample.getCoordinates() changes, mouseCoordinates is changed, baseCoordinates is also changing, which it shouldnt, since there are no statements that say so.

                    if (mouseCoordinates[0] != baseCoordinates[0]) {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                totalCoordinates[i] = mouseListenerExample.getCoordinates();
                mouseListenerExample.setCoordinates(baseCoordinates);
                mouseCoordinates = baseCoordinates;
            }
```

Is there some statement that is changing baseCoordinates that I am missing?

Comment: I'm using the debugger to follow what's going on with the whole thing, and it's changing the contents of both arrays. I could post the whole code if that would make it easier, I'm kinda new on this website.

Comment: Never mind as I see the problem. Please see the answer.

Comment: You could use a java.awt.Point to hold one X, Y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Your `baseCoordinates` variable has been declared `final`, and so it cannot change, but since it is an `int[]` or int-array, it is a *reference* variable, and so what cannot change is the reference itself, not the state of the reference, and so the ints held within the array *can* (and in your case -- *do*) change.

You're changing the values held by `mouseCoordinates`. Since the `baseCoordinates` refers to the *exact same* `int[]` object, then this will likewise change the values for `baseCoordinates`. Best to create a completely new int object for the final variable if you don't want it changed.

Do something like:

```
final int[] baseCoordinates = new int[mouseCoordinates.length];
System.arraycopy( mouseCoordinates, 0, baseCoordinates , 0, mouseCoordinates.length );
```

Comment: If it were you, what would you add? Could i make a final int that is equal to 0 and fill the array with it?

Comment: We have 2020. You can use `final int[] baseCoordinates = mouseCoordinates.clone();` or `final int[] baseCoordinates = Arrays.copyOf(mouseCoordinates, mouseCoordinates.length);` using `System.arraycopy` manually is rarely needed.

Comment: @BigBoi perhaps, you are better off not using arrays. There is already a `Point` class. But if you prefer immutable value types, create your own `Point` like `final class Point { final int x, y; }`. Or with the preview features of the most recent JDK: `record Point(int x, int y) {}`

Answer (score 0):

So after some looking around, i just replaced the arrays with individual ints, and added a print statement right before the break, and it made it work.